# Reverse proxy with apache, specific location to redirect traffic does not work

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

My plan is to use apache web server as a reverse proxy to redirect all traffic to another machine on same network.
The idea is to use redirection by specific locations in apache config files like

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>   
    ServerName localhost   
    ProxyPreserveHost On  

    ProxyPass /cloud http://localhost:1111/   
    ProxyPassReverse /cloud http://localhost:1111/   

    ProxyPass /test http://localhost:2222/   
    ProxyPassReverse /test http://localhost:2222/   
    
    RewriteEngine On   
    
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>    
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security \"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload\"   
    </IfModule>   

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log   
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

where location `/cloud` should redirect traffic to `localhost` port `1111` and location `/test` should redirect traffic to `localhost` port `2222`. Works, without the rewrite rule.

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>   
    ServerName localhost   
    ProxyPreserveHost On   

    ProxyPass /cloud http://localhost:1111/
    ProxyPassReverse /cloud http://localhost:1111/

    ProxyPass /test http://localhost:2222/   
    ProxyPassReverse /test http://localhost:2222/

    RewriteEngine On   
    
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security \"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload\"
    </IfModule>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 

    __  RewriteRule /~* http://9gag.com__ 

</VirtualHost>
```

On activating rewrite rule, "suddenly" all traffic will be redirected to that url including path with `/cloud` and `/test`.

What might be wrong there? What is correct way to use apache as a rewrite proxy?

Comment: Sry. I'm not able to format correctly into code :(

Comment: Without proper formatting, it was unreadable.  Fixed it, the first one is free :).  When you post a question look at the result and fix it accordingly.

Comment: The only difference I see between both configs is `__  RewriteRule /~* http://9gag.com__` right?  What are those `__` chars?  That is not valid Apache config syntax IFAIK.

Comment: From https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect, *as a RewriteRule will usually take effect before a ProxyPass, and so may preempt what you're trying to accomplish.*.  So modify your `ProxyPass` directives into `RewriteRule` with flag `[L,P]` instead.  Keep the `ProxyPassReverse` lines.

Comment: To see it in play, configure your LogLevel to trace8, you will see everything that is going on with the proxy and rewrite engines.  The log messages will be in your error log.  Do not forget to remove it when done, it creates a LOT of logs.

Comment: @Nic3500 Wow thanks for formatting. I tried to fix it, but without success. Unfortunately the review screen showed errors for some code characters without correct markup signs but I'm pretty sure that I formatted all codes correctly. Posting (-> knlcking "activate" (?) button) only worked without review option. You know the result :(.

Comment: @Nic3500 In a documentation (for this site? I forgot the link) one paragraph shows some characters for text formattings like big, bold, ... I wanted to highlight theis line with big, the option in the doc was `__`. Not correct as I see. -> So just text formatting, no config option.

Comment: @Nic3500 You mean my sorting for `proxypass` and `rewriterule` is incorrect? Cool, would be easy, gonna try that later.

Comment: I would try: remove ProxyPass, and replace them with RewriteRule [P,L].  That L flag will ensure it is the last processed rule.  Then the order in which you have them right now would be ok.